# LED size nomenclature

Tags: terminology

Round LEDs are often indicated by "T-1" for 3mm LEDs or "T-1 3/4" for 5mm LEDs. What does the "T" mean, and how should I read other indications like this when I encounter them? "T" doesn't seem to fit neither mm nor inches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this page](http://www.chml.com/service#22):

> The T-1-3/4 nomenclature indicates the shape and size of that particular device. The T or various other descriptions (S, G, PR, TL, etc.) indicates the envelope shape of the device [...]. The 1-3/4 indicates the envelope size in eighths (0.125) of an inch. An example is a T-1-3/4 lamp has a 0.219 diameter (1.75 X 0.125 = 0.219).

So `T-1` is 1/8 inch, or (about) 3mm, `T-1 3/4` is 1.75 \$\times\$ 1/8 inch, or (about) 5mm. A 10mm LED is `T-3 1/4`.